Unable to install Ubuntu20.04 on gigabyte aorus 16x 2024
My laptop is very new with 14th i7 cpu and rtx4070, i am installing the dual boot of Ubuntu 20.04, everything is good except when i was in Ubuntu installation type, installation type is empty and nothing there, but i already seperated a unallocated disk on Windows11.enter image description here

The distribution you use must be newer than your hardware, sometimes 6 months or a year. That way you have newest kernel & drivers required for that newer hardware. Try 24.04.1. Is this laptop or motherboard. And it would help if screen shot was English. Some posts with older Aorus systems mention you have to have latest UEFI & SSD firmware.  You may also need some setting changes in UEFI.
